# Determining Trending Hashtags

Tags: 2013, hashtags

How are trending tags determined? Is there a certain number of times that a hashtag has to be used to be considered trending? Is the min number of times dynamic / based on use of other tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trending Hashtags is found using the GetTrendingTags method of Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.

It builds the following search query `ContentTypeId:0x01FD* write>="Now-6days"` with the Refiners property set to `Tags(filter=20/0/*,sort=frequency/descending)`

ContentTypeId:0x01FD* matches NewsFeed posts and replies.

This all boils down to this definition of Trending Hashtags:

**The top 20 tags used in NewsFeed entries the last week (actually 6 days)**